# How to convert bind() pass through (to on()) to delegate()-like right inside jQuery 1.7.1 code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, drupal-7, jquery-1.7

I'm trying to make some Drupal 7 content updated by jQuery's `load()` and it's not being processed by the relevant JS code. The code in question uses `bind()` and is spread over dozens of Drupal core JS files.

I want to workaround this by using jQuery 1.7.1 and changing

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},
```

to behave as

```
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
},
```

The only thing missing is `selector` as you can see. Can I somehow get it from the standard `bind()` calls?

Comment: Probably not; that's the fundamental difference between the "bind" and "delegate" handling models. *edit* you definitely should not do this to the jQuery library itself; untold amounts of other code could/would break. There's not always a selector string available in a jQuery object - consider `$(this)` inside an event handler. When a jQuery object is constructed around a DOM node or around a string (to construct new nodes), there is no selector, so `.bind()` is the only way to bind handlers.

Comment: Wow that would be fun to debug once you'd forgotten about the change

Comment: (Preemptive rebuttal rebuttal:) The alternative of just using "body" when there's no selector would break situations wherein a handler needs to stop event bubbling for one reason or another. That's another significant semantic difference between "delegate" and "bind".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
function(types, data, fn) {
    (this.context
      ? $(this.context)
      : this ).on(types, this.selector || null, data, fn);
    return this;
}
```

as every jQuery object holds the current selectors and context elements as properties.

However, you should not apply that *workaround* by overwriting `.bind` with the `delegate` funcionality, it will only introduce bugs into your application. Better change your code which invokes bind but shouldn't.

Comment: This breaks things about the way "bind" works, of course. There's not always a value for `this.selector` for one thing, and code that expects its event handlers to be able to stop propagation will also be broken.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's far from the best way to go. But I want to try it because there is really a lot of `bind`s I'll have to rewrite.

Comment: It will only introduce unpredictable behaviour to your app. As Pointy and I mentioned, that workaround might not always work and possibly break other features - so you would need to track down those bugs. You rather want to go systematically through your code base and fix the base issue.

Comment: @int_ua Also note that it may *break* any number of *other* Drupal plugins you want to use. Really it's going to be far more difficult to deal with the ramifications of a change like this than it would be to fix the code.

Comment: and the first thing broken is part of my own JS: `jQuery(window).bind('hashchange'`. Ok, marking this as solved and trying to make it right. @Pointy: I think you deserve bounty also so if you want you can add your answer and I'll reward the bounty when it's available.

Comment: @int_ua thanks but there's no need; I've got plenty of points :-) I'm happy enough just because you've been saved from a bad decision!

Comment: I've tried it with the latest edit that added tertiary operator. It didn't break anything I've checked but also haven't fixed my problem...